# angularjs ng-grid dropdown not working with order by

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an angular grid (ng-grid) where one ove the columns has a dropdown which is bound to a property of the objects displayed in the rows.

```
<div class="gridStyle span9" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div> 

$scope.types = ['cat', 'dog' 'rat'];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data : 'AnimalData',
    columnDefs : [{
        field : 'name',
        displayName : 'Name'
    }, {
        field : 'birthday',
        displayName : 'Birthday'
    },{
        field : 'type',
        displayName : 'type'
        cellTemplate : 'cellTemplate.html'
    }]
};
```

cellTemplate.html:

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="AnimalData[ row.rowIndex ].type">
    <option ng-repeat="item in types">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This binds to my objects perfectly well but when I order my grid the dropdowns do not order they just stay in the same place with the values not changing. How would i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the issue.  To reference the original object you need to change

`AnimalData[ row.rowIndex ].type` to `row.entity.myEditableProperty.type`

eg:

```
<div><select ng-model="row.entity.myEditableProperty.type" ng-options="item for item in types"></select></div>
```

Proof of concept Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/i7vXng?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately get the same result if I do it this way.